# Telegram-bot on AIOgram. Pass message from message.handler to callback.handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am making a telegram bot on aiogram. Can't pass variables from message.handler to callback.handler. I use FSM, in message.handler state = "waiting_for_address".

The algorithm is => in message.handler, the bot sends inline_keyboard with the "Take" button to the GROUP. When the button is clicked, a callback is sent and the bot visits callback.handler. The state (state = "waiting_for_address") is saved, but only for the user who used the bot. But when we click the button, another user appears and has no state set. If I manually set the state in callback.handler, then the bot stops working.

Tell me, please, how to do it right?

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.waiting_for_address)
    async def address_enter(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
            inline_button = InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Take order', callback_data='take')
            inline_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, one_time_keyboard=True).add(inline_button)
            address = message.text

        await state.update_data(myTelephone=await getPhone(mydb,message))
        await state.update_data(myAddress=address)
        await state.update_data(myId=message.from_user.id)

        user_data = await state.get_data()

        chatId = '-###'

        await bot.send_message(chatId, text=emoji.emojize(f"❗️ <b>New order</b> ❗️\nAddress : <b>{user_data['myAddress']}</b>\nCustomers telephone number : <b>{user_data['myTelephone']}</b>"),parse_mode='html',reply_markup = inline_keyboard)
        await message.answer('Your order is sent',parse_mode='html')

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'take' )
async def agree_ref_start(query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if query.data == 'take':
        await query.answer("I am callback!")
        
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id, text=emoji.emojize(f"✅ <b>Order is accepted</b> ✅\nАдрес : <b>{user_data['myAddress']}</b>\nCustomer telephone : <b>{user_data['myTelephone']}</b>\nOrder is accepted by @{query.from_user.username}"),parse_mode='html', reply_markup=None)
        await bot.send_message(user_data['myId'],f"✅Your order is accepted\nYour telephone number <b>{user_data['myTelephone']}</b>\ndriver id - {query.from_user.id} ",parse_mode='html')

        await state.finish()
```